# format xml template for the custom variables using freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I was using freemarker to format template for my custom variables in xml like _prop.Var1. Below is data where i was saving the context of all props in map and trying to format the variables using the map.

<myDoc>

<props>

<prop name="Var1" value="XXX" />

</props>

<myEle att1="${_prop.Var1}" />

</myDoc>

Below is code snippet which i am using:

template.process(variables, out);

Note: variables is a map which contains all the properties of name value pairs.
variables: {Var1:XXX}, tried with map : {_prop.Var1:XXX} but this also doesn't worked.

Here is the exception which i am getting while using the above code line.

---

## *Edited:*

freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> verbose  [in template "template" at line 1, column 83]

---

### Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):

### - Failed at: ${_prop.Var1}  [in template "template" at line 3, column 63]

```
at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134) ~[freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.newDesciptionBuilder(UnexpectedTypeException.java:80) ~[freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.<init>(UnexpectedTypeException.java:43) ~[freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.core.NonHashException.<init>(NonHashException.java:49) ~[freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.core.Dot._eval(Dot.java:48) ~[freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:81) ~[freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.calculateInterpolatedStringOrMarkup(DollarVariable.java:96) ~[freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:59) ~[freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:327) [freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:333) [freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:306) [freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:386) [freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:2.3.25]
```

Kindly help me out from this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't show the error message, only the location.

Comment: @ddekany Thanks for your reply. I have added the stacktrace which describes the error message. Please help from this.

Comment: No, the error message is still missing. It's shown before the location and the stack trace.

Comment: @ddekany Thanks again for your reply. Pasted another message (see Edited section). Kindly check now and help in this. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the message and the strack trace below it comes from the same exception? Because the error message refers to `verbose` in line 1 column 83 (and I don't even see a variable called "verbose" in the example template), and the stack trace refers to `_prop` at line 3, column 63. Anyway, the thing whose stack trace you have sent suggests that the thing in the left side of the dot (`_prop`) doesn't exist or is `null`. Have you put it into the data-model, with exactly that name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you are saying "tried with map : {_prop.Var1:XXX} but this also doesn't worked". I'm not sure what that exactly means (like, what the Java code is), but if you have tried something like `variables.put("_prop.Var1", "XXX")`, then that won't work because when in the template you write `_prop.Var1` then FreeMarker will first look for `_prop`, and if that's found, then inside that it looks for `Var1`. It will not look for the "_prop.Var1" key (for that you had to write `_prop\.Var1` in the template, so that it treats the dot as part of the name, not as an operator). For `_prop.Var1` in the template to work, you had to do something like:

```
Map<String, Object> prop = new HashMap<>();
variables.put("_prop", prop);
prop.put("Var1", "XXX");
... add further subvariables to prop
```

BTW `prop` need not be a `Map`, it can also be a Java bean with the desired bean properties. So like if it's a public class with `public String getVar1() { return "XXX"; }`, then you can refer to that as `_prop.var1` (with lower case `v`, as the JavaBeans specification says so).

Comment: thanks a lot! this is what i was looking and my issue got resolve d with the approach variables.put("_prop", prop), thank you so much :)